# Automapper и Nullable свойства

Tags: c#, automapper

Есть модель и дто

```
public class Model
{
  public int? SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Dto
{
  public int? SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

при маппинге через автомаппер я получаю `InvalidOperationException` с текстом

> Нулевой объект должен иметь значение

Я, конечно, могу сделать маппинг через условие

```
.ForMember(d => d.SomeProperty, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.SomeProperty == null ? null : s.SomeProperty))
```

Но блин, почему я должен сообщать мапперу, что nullable свойство должно стать null если источник null?

Comment: Выглядит как баг. Возможно, стоило писать о нем не сюда, а разработчикам автомаппера?